# Create nginx subdomain for a webpage

Tags: docker, nginx

I am currently running nginx and nginx proxymanager in docker.

What I want to do is have a subdomain for a webpage.

For example,

instead of:

```
https://example.com/test
```

I want to have:

```
https://test.example.com
```

Any help on how to configure this?
This is a fresh installation of nginx and nginx proxy manager

I tried to configure it inside of the nginx proxy manager but I’m unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey it should work if you just set domain name as test.example.com

In case a nginx config could like like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.example.com;
  
  location / {
   proxy_pass http://your_ip:your_port;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a webpage on example.org but idk like to run a different webpage on test.example.org would this work? Thank you

Comment: Yeah just instead of example.org you put test.example.org as domain name